# Reload with query parameters Sitecore Forms custom submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms

I Have Created custom submit action in sitecore 9 forms.

In that custom action, I want to reload a same the page with adding of query parameters.

So far I tried.

```
 Log.Error(Error, typeof(SendDataToApi));
 Log.Error(ErrorDescription, typeof(SendDataToApi));
 //Redirect to a Error Page
 var defaultUrlOptions = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
 defaultUrlOptions.SiteResolving = Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving;
 formSubmitContext.RedirectUrl = new UrlString(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item, defaultUrlOptions)) + "?apierror=true";
 formSubmitContext.RedirectOnSuccess = true;
 formSubmitContext.Abort();
```

It Reloads the page but the querystring was not added ?

Any Help..

Answer (score 0):

Property that you tries to use is considered to be used for **Success** form submit

```
formSubmitContext.RedirectUrl = new UrlString(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item, defaultUrlOptions)) + "?apierror=true";
formSubmitContext.RedirectOnSuccess = true;
```

but, you abort context. It means that forms fails.

```
formSubmitContext.Abort();
```

You can try to use standard ASP.Net approach for redirect:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect(new UrlString(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item, defaultUrlOptions)) + "?apierror=true", false);
```

Comment: But I need to redirect in method not in a Action Result.(Response.Redrect is available in Action Result)

Comment: @Rajasekar what is stopping you from calling an ActionResult method from a non ActionResult method?